# Replace len in python

Tags: python

I would like the python code to output the same result without using len? How do I go about doing it?

```
rainbow_colors=["red","orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
print("THE ORIGINAL COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : " )

for j in range(len(rainbow_colors)):
    print("#",(j+1),":",rainbow_colors[j])

favorite_color = input("Enter your favorite color: ")
new_colors = [sub.replace('blue', favorite_color) for sub in rainbow_colors]

print("THE NEW COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : " )
for k in range(len(new_colors)):
    print("#",(k+1),":",new_colors[k])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumerate. The start argument specifies the index you want to start enumerating at.

```
for color_num, color in enumerate(rainbow_colors, start=1):
    print(color_num, color)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rainbow_colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
print("THE ORIGINAL COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : ")

for index, element in enumerate(rainbow_colors):
    print(f'# {index + 1} : {element}')

favorite_color = input("Enter your favorite color: ")
new_colors = [sub.replace('blue', favorite_color) for sub in rainbow_colors]

print("THE NEW COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : ")
for index, element in enumerate(new_colors):
    print(f'# {index + 1} : {element}')
```

You can use the enumerate function. It runs through a list and takes the position (index) and the value associated. It is much cleaner and no need to use the len() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get access of the index of the current iteration along with the value of the iteration:

```
rainbow_colors=["red","orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]

print("THE ORIGINAL COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : " )

for i,j in enumerate(rainbow_colors):
    print("#",(i+1),":",j)

favorite_color = input("Enter your favorite color: ")

new_colors = [favorite_color if sub is 'blue' else sub for sub in rainbow_colors]

print("THE NEW COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : " )

for i,j in enumerate(new_colors):
    print("#",(i+1),":",j)
```

Output:

```
THE ORIGINAL COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : 
# 1 : red
# 2 : orange
# 3 : yellow
# 4 : green
# 5 : blue
# 6 : indigo
# 7 : violet
Enter your favorite color: pink
THE NEW COLORS OF THE RAINBOW ARE : 
# 1 : red
# 2 : orange
# 3 : yellow
# 4 : green
# 5 : pink
# 6 : indigo
# 7 : violet
```